# PHP Late Binding Static with private __construct

Tags: php, abstract-class, late-static-binding

I have an abstract class that has a function which uses PHP's Late Static Binding, as follows:

```
abstract class MetaComponent {
    public static function do(...$args) {
        return new static(...$args);
    }
}
```

Then, I implemented the abstract class this way:

```
class ¬Text extends MetaComponent {
    private function __construct(string $text) {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function render() {
        echo $this->text;
    }
}
```

My intention was that no one could instantiate `¬Text` directly, so I made the `__construct` function private. However, anyone should be able to instantiate it through `¬Text::do('Lorem Ipsum')`. This is why I used Late Binding Static within `MetaComponent::do()`.

However, I get the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to private ¬Text::__construct() from context 'MetaComponent' in /xxx/MetaComponent.php:9`

Is there a way to call the constructor from the abstract class while preventing `__construct` from being called directly?

Comment: Use `protected`, not `private`.

Comment: It works, thanks. Should I delete this question or what?

Comment: There aren't any down votes or close votes, so I suppose the community's opinion would be "nah". Someone googling this particular combination of keywords might benefit from landing here as well.